# What are the risks of placing Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) in VCS repositories?

Tags: threat-mitigation, threat-modeling, aws, amazon

Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) uniquely identify AWS resources. Amazon requires an ARN when you need to specify a resource unambiguously across all of AWS, such as in IAM policies, Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) tags, and API calls.

Here are some example of ARNs:

```
<!-- Elastic Beanstalk application version -->
arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:123456789012:environment/My App/MyEnvironment

<!-- IAM user name -->
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/David

<!-- Amazon RDS instance used for tagging -->
arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:123456789012:db:mysql-db

<!-- Object in an Amazon S3 bucket -->
arn:aws:s3:::my_corporate_bucket/exampleobject.png
```

My question: what are the risks if these types of information are made available on a version control system such as Bitbucket or Github?

Answer (score 1):

Probably none, unless you have insecure users.

I base this largely on the [AWS Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) documentation, which (1) says nothing about protecting your account ID, and (2) encourages using roles to permit inter-account access. Since a role ARN contains the account ID, and they don't explicitly caution you to only share the ARN with a trusted party, one can assume that the account ID isn't very valuable.

That said, the account ID can be used to access a sign-in page that's specific to your account. If you have users with easily guessable names and passwords, it's possible that knowledge of your account ID can give attackers a way to exploit those users. I don't know how or if Amazon responds to brute force login attempts, so this may not be an issue either.